# Drupal - Only local files should be passed to _locale_parse_js_file()

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I'm relatively new to Drupal and working on a Drupal9 project hosted on Acquia. As part of the project requirements, I deployed a new Google verification `HTML` file to the repository and then executed the `drush deploy` command. The `drush deploy` command performed cache rebuild, configuration import, and deployment hooks.

However, after completing these steps, I'm encountering an error when trying to access the site. The specific error message is:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

```
Exception: Only local files should be passed to _locale_parse_js_file(). in _locale_parse_js_file() (line 1110 of core/modules/locale/locale.module).
locale_js_translate(Array) (Line: 509)
locale_js_alter(Array, Object, NULL) (Line: 562)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter('js', Array, Object) (Line: 277)
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getJsAssets(Object, ) (Line: 319)
Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAssetLibraries(Object, Array) (Line: 158)
Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAttachments(Object) (Line: 45)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HtmlResponseSubscriber->onRespond(Object, 'kernel.response', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.response', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.response') (Line: 202)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(Object, Object, 2) (Line: 148)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 2) (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 270)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware->bypass(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 143)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 54)
Drupal\tibco_trusted_reverse_proxy\StackMiddleware\TrustedReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 2, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 2) (Line: 166)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber->makeSubrequest(Object, '/node/21091', 403) (Line: 119)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber->makeSubrequestToCustomPath(Object, '/node/21091', 403) (Line: 71)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber->on403(Object) (Line: 109)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HttpExceptionSubscriberBase->onException(Object, 'kernel.exception', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.exception', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.exception') (Line: 229)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleThrowable(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 92)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 270)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware->bypass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 226)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 54)
Drupal\tibco_trusted_reverse_proxy\StackMiddleware\TrustedReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 709)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Now the website is down with this message.Also I am not able to access the admin side. I have restored the database backup from a previous day , but it is showing the same error.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!